# Remove duplicate sets of values in 2d array (regardless of the order or keys in each row)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, unique

I have an array with the following structure:

```
[
    ["venue1" => 1, "venue2" => 2],
    ["venue1" => 3, "venue2" => 4],
    ["venue1" => 2, "venue2" => 1],
    ["venue1" => 5, "venue2" => 6],
]
```

I need to remove the duplicate "pair of values", in this case row [0] and row [2].

I tried it with that code, but it doesn't work (and of course it's not very elegant).

```
foreach ( $compare_arr as $v1 ) 
{
    $key = array_search( intval($v1[venue1]), array_column( $compare_arr, 'venue2' ) );
    if ( $key <> '' ) unset($compare_arr[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: The *pair* of values for [0] and [2] are the same (1+2 and 2+1)

Comment: I added my current approach for a possible solution. Maybe someone has an idea why it doesn't work or a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach where an intermediate array is formed of sorted values.  That you can then search for to find duplicate pairs to remove.

```
<?php

$venues = 
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 1,
      'venue2' => 2,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 3,
      'venue2' => 4,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 2,
      'venue2' => 1,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 5,
      'venue2' => 6,
    ),
);

$result = $pairs = $venues;
array_walk($pairs, 'sort');

var_export($pairs);

foreach($pairs as $k => $pair) {
    if(count(array_keys($pairs, $pair)) > 1) {
        unset($result[$k]);
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 1,
      1 => 2,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 3,
      1 => 4,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 1,
      1 => 2,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 5,
      1 => 6,
    ),
  )array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 3,
      'venue2' => 4,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 5,
      'venue2' => 6,
    ),
  )
```

If you want to remove occurring duplicates rather than pruning out duplicates altogether, you can do an array_unique on the sorted array above and then use the remaining keys to filter the original array.

```
$tmp     = $venues;
array_walk($tmp, 'sort');
$tmp     = array_unique($tmp, SORT_REGULAR);
$result  = array_intersect_key($venues, $tmp);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 1,
      'venue2' => 2,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 3,
      'venue2' => 4,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'venue1' => 5,
      'venue2' => 6,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks very good! :-)

It it possible not to completely remove *both* duplicate pairs and instead let *one* of them stay? (so that the result is an array with 1/2, 3/4 and 5/6 )

Comment: @o.heinrich you can just use array_unique to obtain unique occurrences on the intermediate array above, and use that to filter the original array.  Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You might also first loop the array creating a compound key based on the ordered keys.

Then you can filter the result only keeping arrays where the count is 2 as nothing is added because there are no duplicates.

For example

```
$result = [];
$compare_arr = [
    ["venue1" => 1, "venue2" => 2],
    ["venue1" => 3, "venue2" => 4],
    ["venue1" => 2, "venue2" => 1],
    ["venue1" => 5, "venue2" => 6],
];

foreach ($compare_arr as $v1) {
    sort($v1);
    $cKey = $v1[0] .'-'. $v1[1];
    if (array_key_exists($cKey, $result)) {
        $result[$cKey][] = $v1;
        continue;
    }
    $result[$cKey] = $v1;
}
$result = array_filter($result, function($item) {
    return count($item) === 2;
});

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [3-4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [5-6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
        )

)
```

You can see the compound keys are the values with a `-` in between. If you want to have the keys numbered from 0, you can use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/I060q)

**Edit**

If you want to keep the first matching single pair, you can check for the compound key and if it already exists continue the loop without overwriting the existing one.

```
$result = [];
$compare_arr = [
    ["venue1" => 1, "venue2" => 2],
    ["venue1" => 3, "venue2" => 4],
    ["venue1" => 2, "venue2" => 1],
    ["venue1" => 5, "venue2" => 6]
];

foreach ($compare_arr as $v1) {
    sort($v1);
    $cKey = $v1[0] .'-'. $v1[1];
    if (array_key_exists($cKey, $result)) {
        continue;
    }
    $result[$cKey] = $v1;
}

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1-2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3-4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [5-6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/6F1fl)

Comment: This a a great solution as well! :-)

How can it be modified so that one of the duplicate pairs remains?
(as a result an array with 1/2, 3/4 and 5/6 is needed)

Comment: @o.heinrich I have added another example for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use a classic `foreach()` loop or functional iteration, there is no reason to iterate the input array more than once.

This snippet will appear nearly identical to TheFourthBird's answer, but I don't like the unnecessary use of `continue`. This snippet will ensure no that rows in the result array have 100% shared venue values (in any order). The subarray keys will also not suffer reordering; in other words the first element key will be `venue1` then the second element will be `venue2`.  Using `implode()` offers additional flexibility because the code won't need to be altered if the number of elements in each row changes.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    sort($row);
    $key = implode('-', $row);
    $result[$key] ??= $row;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'venue1' => 1,
    'venue2' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'venue1' => 3,
    'venue2' => 4,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'venue1' => 5,
    'venue2' => 6,
  ),
)
```

---

To completely remove all rows where venue values are shared, maintain a "found" array as well as a "result" array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hiCP3))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $index => $row) {
    sort($row);
    $key = implode('-', $row);
    if (!isset($found[$key])) {
        $found[$key] = true;
        $result[$key] = $data[$index];
    } else {
        unset($result[$key]);
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Or mutate the input array directly. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/9eP09)

```
foreach ($data as $index => $row) {
    sort($row);
    $key = implode('-', $row);
    if (!isset($found[$key])) {
        $found[$key] = $index;
    } else {
        unset($data[$index], $data[$found[$key]]);
    }
}
var_export(array_values($data));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'venue1' => 3,
    'venue2' => 4,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'venue1' => 5,
    'venue2' => 6,
  ),
)
```